# Using Packer to Spin a VM and extract the image in an availability set

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, packer, azure-availability-set

We have our corporate requirement ( due to pricing and whitelisting) to have Availability sets in our Azure subscription and resources like Compute should be spun inside that particular availability set. Since Packer while creating the Image spins up a temporary VM inside a temporary resource Group  , I am confused (since did not find any documentation around it) if we can configure packer to spin the temporary VM inside the whitelisted availability set.

One possible way I can think of is to spin up the VM in the **Resource Group which we created for the Availability Set (Since everything in Azure needs to be inside the Resource Group)** that way I am guessing it will be tracked as part of billing but I am still not sure if the intermittent VM will be part of availability set.

Please help and suggest if there is an alternate way to the same .

Comment: Placing a VM (via Packer or any other means) to the same resource group where an availability set is already existing, doesn't automatically put that VM inside the availability set. If that is what you are wondering on your second paragraph. I don't personally believe there is a way to take advantage of availability set for Packer, since at least according to the documentation there isn't a parameter for it.

Comment: Thanks @AnttiP for answer , well my possible thought was a guess . Thanks for confirming it will not work , I was also having second thoughts on it . For getting clarity I have posted my question on Packer github as issue as well . Let's see what I get as a reply .

Comment: The github issue I was referring earlier is :- https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/6290